# Google Maps API Circle Intersect Detection

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to figure out of it's possible to detect when two Google Maps circles (around markers) intersect or bump into each other.

What I want to accomplish is, if two circles intersect, I want to raise an event. I'm not sure if this is possible though.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the distance between the centers of the circles, if it is less than the sum of the radius of the two circles, they intersect.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/o5veapsx/7/)

(based off of the code in Larry Dukek's answer, but using native Google Maps Javascript API v3 functions from the geometry library)

[image: screenshot of example]

**code snippet:**

```js
let map;

function initMap() {
  // Create the map.
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 41.081301,
      lng: -98.214219
    },
    zoom: 25
  });

  var c0 = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: '#0000FF',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#0000FF',
    fillOpacity: 0.2,
    map: map,
    center: {
      lat: 41.082953,
      lng: -98.215285
    },
    radius: 200
  });

  var c1 = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.2,
    map: map,
    center: {
      lat: 41.081070,
      lng: -98.214027
    },
    radius: 34.692866520
  });
  console.log("c1 & c0 hasIntersections returns:" + hasIntersections(c1, c0));
  var c2 = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: '#00FF00',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#00FF00',
    fillOpacity: 0.2,
    map: map,
    center: {
      lat: 41.083313,
      lng: -98.211635
    },
    radius: 34.692866520
  });
  console.log("c2 & c0 hasIntersections returns:" + hasIntersections(c2, c0));
}

function hasIntersections(circle0, circle1) {
  var center0 = circle0.getCenter();
  var center1 = circle1.getCenter();

  var maxDist = circle0.getRadius() + circle1.getRadius();
  var actualDist = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(center0, center1);

  return maxDist >= actualDist;
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Circles</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=geometry&v=weekly&channel=2" async></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some JavaScript that will detect if two circles intersect

```
 var e = Math;         // shortcut for the mathematical function 
 var D2R = e.PI/180.0; // value used for converting degrees to radians

 Number.prototype.toRadians = function() {
   return this * D2R;
 };

 function distance(lat0,lng0,lat1,lng1){

   // convert degrees to radians
   var rlat0 = lat0.toRadians();
   var rlng0 = lng0.toRadians();
   var rlat1 = lat1.toRadians();
   var rlng1 = lng1.toRadians();

   // calculate the differences for both latitude and longitude (the deltas)
   var Δlat=(rlat1-rlat0);
   var Δlng=(rlng1-rlng0);

   // calculate the great use haversine formula to calculate great-circle distance between two points
   var a = e.pow(e.sin(Δlat/2),2) + e.pow(e.sin(Δlng/2),2)*e.cos(rlat0)*e.cos(rlat1);
   var c = 2*e.asin(e.sqrt(a));
   var d = c * 6378137;  // multiply by the radius of the great-circle (average radius of the earth in meters)

   return d;
 }

  function hasIntersections(circle0,circle1){
    var center0 = circle0.getCenter();
    var center1 = circle1.getCenter();

    var maxDist = circle0.getRadius()+circle1.getRadius();
    var actualDist = distance(center0.lat(),center0.lng(),center1.lat(),center1.lng());

    return maxDist>=actualDist;
  }
```

Just call hasIntersections with the references to your circles.  Here is an example that showing two circles almost touching (returning false) and if you change the zero to a one in c1 they will touch (returning true).

```
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 41.081301, lng: -98.214219},
      zoom: 25
    });

    var c0 = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeOpacity: .1,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: '#0000FF',
        fillOpacity: .2,
        map: map,
        center: {lat:41.082953, lng:  -98.215285},
        radius: 200
      });

    var c1 =new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeOpacity: .1,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: .2,
        map: map,
        center: {lat:41.081070, lng: -98.214027},
        radius: 34.692866520
      });
      console.log(hasIntersections(c1,c0));
```

Comment: Hello, the function returns in the console an error: "Uncaught TypeError: circle0.getCenter is not a function", could you check this? For this solution is also important to me.